# System working but i see just black screen after restarts and shutdowns

Tags: boot, shutdown, screen, reboot

I have this problem in all Linux distros. The problem is when i try to shutdown PC, PC goes off but screen stays black, I mean not turn off.

[image: image of the problem]

When I try to restart, same thing happen. Screen stays black but system works in background. For example I can open chrome if I know exact place of the icon but I cant see.

I tried `nomodeset`, blacklist `nouveau` and these kind of things. `acpi=force` something like that.

could you help me please?

thanks

edit: the worst part of the problem is just the solution unplug monitor caple and plug in and it works until next shutdown/restart.

PC specs:

```
gpu : rtx 2060
cpu : i5 9600kf
mb  : msi mpg z390 gaming plus
```